# Merge via openid does not reassociate migrated questions

Tags: bug, migration, openid, migrated-questions, merge-accounts

On Astro.SE we had a slight issue with a user who had asked [a question on Space.SE that got migrated over](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/534/should-i-focus-more-on-aperture-or-focal-length-for-a-telescope).

He seemed to have two accounts, and had logged in with account A, while the question was asked by account B. Account B had never logged in to Astro, thus the question had a greyed out owner.

He followed the openid merge process: To manually merge two accounts, one can just add the openid of the other one via my logins, and the accounts merge. He did this from account A.

However, the migrated question did not automatically get reassociated to his merged account, even though both openids were in account A on Astro.

This would not have happened if he had logged in with account B (triggering the reassociation of the question), and *then* openid merged.

Can this be fixed? Basically, when a user merges two accounts via the openid merge route, the system should check for any leftover migration stubs linked to the incoming account and reassociate them with the new merged account.